# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when using arcgis javascript in node.js

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cors

I meet a problem when using ArcGIS JavaScript (version 4.9) to handle map data. the following is my code snippet:

```
 esriConfig.request.trustedServers.push("https://XXX.XXX.XX.118:3070");
    ...
newBasemap = new TileLayer({
                                    url: "https://arcgis.tpgos.gov.taipei/arcgis/rest/services/ED/GD_Plain_Service/MapServer",
                                    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
                                    spatialReference: { wkid: 102443 }
                                });
if (newBasemap != undefined) {
                            map.add(newBasemap);
                        }/
```

and this cause an error message.
The Error message show [Access to image ...from origin ... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.]

And I found the image element not insert into map object, it is reject when fetching then throw the error. So I use following codes to catch event before image loading data, but it is still invalid.

```
var observerConfig = { childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to handle mutations
function handleMutations(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        console.log("call event");
        if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
            // Handle added nodes (images)
            $(mutation.addedNodes).filter('img').attr("crossorigin", "true");
        }
    });
}

// Create a new MutationObserver with the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(handleMutations);

// Start observing the target node (divmap) and the specified configuration
observer.observe(document.getElementById('divmap'), observerConfig);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The below plain JS code works without any problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Linked Maps Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/esri/themes/light/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height:100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  <script>
    require([
      "esri/config",
      "esri/Basemap",
      "esri/layers/TileLayer",
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView"
    ],
    function (esriConfig,Basemap, TileLayer, Map, MapView) {
      const layer = new TileLayer({
        url: "https://arcgis.tpgos.gov.taipei/arcgis/rest/services/ED/GD_Plain_Service/MapServer",
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        spatialReference: {wkid: 102443}
      });
      const customBasemap = new Basemap({
        baseLayers: [layer],
        title: "My Basemap"
      });
      const myMap = new Map({
        basemap: customBasemap
      });
      const view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: myMap
      });
    }
  );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: It can work, but I still meet a problem when using other map server.
I have use  esriConfig.request.trustedServers.push, and it add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when sending json request to the map server, but when query image to map server after that, it cause cors error, and I found the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header of each image query is empty, even I have added option crossOrigin: 'anonymous'.

Comment: And each image ARCGIS query will be combined into a big picture by ARCGIS JAVASCRIPT itself, I found this behavior is not the same as leaflet.js. And that cause the cors error. Do you know anything about this problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, this is not my area so I can't help you any further.

Comment: It is not a freeware, and you have give me a help. Thanks.